# How to connect to mssql using pdo through PHP and Linux?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, connection, pdo

I'm trying to for a new PDO connection using the following code.

```
new PDO("mssql:driver=????;Server={$serverName};Database={$databaseName}", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

I'm not sure what drivers to use? Or how to install them. I can connect perfectly fine using the `mssql_connect` function in PHP but I want to use the PDO library instead.

My `php.ini` settings for mssql are:

```
ssql

MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    1
Library version     FreeTDS

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent  On  On
mssql.batchsize 0   0
mssql.charset   no value    no value
mssql.compatability_mode    Off Off
mssql.connect_timeout   5   5
mssql.datetimeconvert   On  On
mssql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_procs Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.min_error_severity    10  10
mssql.min_message_severity  10  10
mssql.secure_connection Off Off
mssql.textlimit Server default  Server default
mssql.textsize  Server default  Server default
mssql.timeout   60  60
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The PDO mssql driver is no more, use `sqlsrv` (under php windows) or `dblib` (under php linux)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: using dblib still produces the missing drivers error. "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'". I find it strange that mssql_connect works fine yet I have to do something in order to get the PDO side working. I'm not very familiar with linux which means that I'm unsure of getting the drivers that I need sorted out?

Comment: You need to enable pdo_dblib.so in your php.ini and set up FreeTDS under Linux.

Comment: how do you enable pdo_dblib in configure? also I am using centos 5 32bit, how would I set it up?

Comment: pdo_dblib no longer works with PHP 5.4+... I can't find a suitable solution to this problem.

Comment: @James Is the PHP [Microsoft PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) deprecated or is there no problems using it?

Comment: @Abdul Not that I'm aware of, why do you ask?

Comment: @James I misunderstood your answer and thought that you can't use PDOs with mssql, but I'm guessing that's the `PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");` one that you can't use, and I need to import the MS drivers

Comment: Correct, "mssql" stopped being provided with PHP in 5.3 and "sqlsrv" and "dblib" are the current drivers (to my knowledge, it's been a while)

Answer (score 5):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Trying to connect to MSSQL I got "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'". It seems that I was missing the dblib/sybase PHP extension.

I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase freetds-common libsybdb5 \ 
&& sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Works fine now.

Comment: The php-sybase package solved the problem for me. I didn't need to install the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");

$hostname may need to be configured as either...
$hostname.':'.$port;
```

OR

```
$hostname.','.$port;
```

Comment: The error message that I get is

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Answer (score 0):

The dblib/sybase PHP extension tip posted by Karl Wilbur worked for me.
The pre-installation check page for LimeSurvey now shows

#### PHP PDO driver library- Microsoft SQL Server (dblib), MySQL

Just make sure you find and install the version that aligns with the PHP version you are using;

`Prompt>sudo apt-get install php<appropriate version>-sybase freetds-common libsybdb5
Prompt>sudo apache2ctl restart`

Cheers,