# Symfony2, connect to SQLServer from Linux

Tags: php, linux, symfony, pdo

I have this configuratión on my parameters.ini:

```
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_sqlsrv"
    database_host="SERVSGBD"
    database_port=""
    database_name="sqlserver"
    database_user="usr_gitekrrhh"
    database_password="gi$1po(5g."

    mailer_transport="smtp"
    mailer_host="localhost"
    mailer_user=""
    mailer_password=""

    locale="en"

    secret="dcbd3a1edfce4c17bd1b36c34fbdd8b10"
```

When I check if it is working, for example with this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

I´m getting this error:

```
  [PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you look at this:

[Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)

I think this is solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

u need to tell your conifiguration file where to find the PDO Driver for connecting to the Database :)

[Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)