# mssql_connect slow (linux server)

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

Does anyone know why mssql_connect would be slow? PHP is running on a Linux server with FreeTDS. I am trying to connect to a remote database. When I connect from PHP it takes about 3 seconds, but if I use the FreeTDS tsql command from the shell it connects in under a second, so it is able to connect faster. Is there a setting I can change or a different driver I should use?

Comment: Do you have enough remaining database connections?

Answer (score 0):

You should start using PDO with MSSQL driver support.

More info on:

> http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

And some examples:

> [Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)

Comment: PDO is just as slow. I think it uses the same driver as mssql_connect. Also for some reason it also crashes after connecting and I get an empty response.