# PHP Compability with Microsoft SQL server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Can php use Microsoft SQL server for database instead of the internal mysql database? If yes, what is the method of connecting to  MS SQL server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux

Comment: `internal mysql database` ?

Comment: MySQL is not internal to PHP

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: If you mean if the mysqli extension supports SQL Server, well, of course not. That's why it's called mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDO library. It is useful. I used in one bigger project (MS SQL + PHP 5.3).
You also need a proper database driver. First link from Google: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: I suspect Daan means that PDO isn't simply an automagic connection to every possible database, you need to install the MSSQL drivers for PHP whether you use that interface directly, or you use PDO

Comment: You're right. I focused on the source code level (how to access database effectively).

Comment: Note that this only applies if you are running php on windows. linux/php <--> windows/mssql is a pig.