# How to insert data to MSSQL Server with odbc connection in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to insert my data to mssql server with odbc using PHP but it doesnt insert any rows.

Here  My PHP Codes:

```
$q="INSERT INTO dosyadegerlendirme (
                                    YatisNo,
                                    Degerlendirici,
                                    Kodlayici,
                                    HataSeviye,
                                    AnaHataKategoriId,
                                    AnaHataKategori,
                                    AltKategoriId,
                                    AltKategori,
                                    DosyaDonemi,
                                    DegerlendirmeTarihi ) 
    VALUES    (
               '{$_POST['yatisno']}',
               '{$_SESSION['login_user']}',
               '{$_POST['kodcu']}',
               '{$hataSeviye}',
               '{$_POST['AnaHataKategorisi']}', 
               '{$anaKategoriAciklama}',
               '{$_POST['AltHataKategorisi']}',
               '{$altKategoriAciklama}',
               '{$_POST['donem']}',
               '{$_POST['dtarih']}' )";



$result=odbc_exec($baglanti, $q);
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.
```

How can I achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can not say much cause you did not give anything about your server where your app works but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965501/2629508) can help.

Comment: I am not using PDO for database connection.So your link doesnt help me