# Connecting mssql database to GoDaddy host via PHP 5.5 using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

*Previous post which resolved my problem but on my local machine:*

[Connecting to MSSQL server via php-pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203737/connecting-to-mssql-server-via-php-pdo)

**Current error** on GoDaddy host:
Connection failed:

> Connection failed: could not find driver

Does anyone know how do I reach these drivers on GoDaddy (the extension below are installed locally and thanks to them my script works)?

> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
>   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Here is the list (image) with all available extensions that GoDaddy offers:
[image]

Here is the class which I'm using, the parameters are 100% correct and are not an issue here. The thing is I payed a lot of money for this host and now the main problem came up.

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: Why not ask them if you "paid a lot of money"?

Comment: I will do that definitely but I'm trying to see if there is a solution which I'm missing.