# Why can't I connect to mssql server? (PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I'm using the following code to try and connect using:

```
try {
   $hostname = "***********";
   $port = *****;
   $dbname = "******";
   $username = "******";
   $pw = "********";
   $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
   exit;
 }
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver
```

How do I fix this error?

I've seen other answers say that I should have "SQL Server PDO Driver" installed. Is there a way to check this is installed?

Comment: Your operating system/server OS? ODBC driver installed?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Operating system is CENTOS 6.7 . Not sure about the odbc driver that is installed. How could I find that out?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Comment: This link will help you defenitely. https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21567

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system you are running php is Windows, then you have to setup SQL Server php extension as described here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx. If you run PHP on Linux then you have to install the extension php-mssql or odbc drivers:

**PHP and Accessing MS SQL Server in Unix/Linux:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607814/PHP-and-Accessing-MS-SQL-Server-in-Unix-Linux

**Connect remotely to MSSQL with PHP:**
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21567

Also check this related question and answer:
[Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)